Father deliberately ends up in prison to attack the killer of his son
There is a gang shoot out and a young boy is filming but gets shot...
His dad goes mad and beats up and cripples a police officer with a snooker ball in a sock to be sent to the same prison as the man who shot his son....
It ends with a brawl between the two of them where one of them gets shot and killed with a gun he has made in jail.
It finishes with him sat at his graveside apologising and saying he wished it all never happened.

did ti look American? or Asian?

Spoiler for me :(

Sounds like Doing Hard Time (released in 2004). The plot summary listed here aligns perfectly with your recollections.

You might want to explain in your answer why you think it sounds like the movie that the OP is looking for.
